# What are the disadvantage of handling updated_at field at the database level instead of php level in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to update the `updated_at` timestamp even when we make a change directly through the mysql and considering to make these changes:

Adding the following to the User model:

```
public $timestamps = ["created_at"]; //only want to used created_at column
const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

And run the following on MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY (updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON
    UPDATE
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

But I'm not sure if it could cause any issues.

Comment: PSA: The `TIMESTAMP` type is getting dangerous to use as 2038-01-19 is fast approaching.

Comment: If you're modifying things through the database directly, any process that does that should also alter the time. Setting automatic triggers can be trouble as they can fire when you don't want them to, and there's no way to stop them.

Comment: regarding later migrations and project deployments, it´s a serious advantage to UPDATE by your model to keep the definition on your project level and not on the database level